# node-red custom nodes project search path

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

I am using a fairly standard node-red project structure to develop custom nodes:

```
- <myproject>
   - examples
      - example.json
   - nodes
      - node1.html
      - node1.js
   - libs
      - custom_lib (a custom node lib used by nodes)
         ....
   - package.json
```

My `package.json` includes:

```
  ...
  "node-red": {
     "nodes": {
         "node1": "nodes/node1.js"
     }
  },
  "files": [
     "nodes"
     "libs"
  ],
  "scripts": {
     "debug": "set DEBUG=express:* & nodemon node_modules/node-red/red.js --userDir ./userdata --flowFile ./examples/example.json"
  },
  dependencies: {
     ....
  }
```

To install the environment locally, I am running: `npm install .` from within the project. It creates `node_modules` with all the dependencies.

But when I am running `npm run debug`, node-red is not finding the local modules:

```
18 Feb 14:32:27 - [info] Waiting for missing types to be registered:
18 Feb 14:32:27 - [info]  - node1
```

Unless I am manually creating a symlink:

```
ln -s <path_to_myproject> ./node_modules/<module_name>
```

Is there a proper way to install/structure the project so I won't need to add this manual step (i.e. I'd like to create a Docker container by running `npm install ...`)

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following:

```
npm install /path/to/your/custom_node
```

in the Node-RED UserDir ( `.userDir`) it will create the right symlink for you ( your node name in the `.userDir/node_modules` directory)

Guessing at your structure it should be `npm install ..`

EDIT:

Based on the comment and remembering how npm works, you will need a directory structure as follows:

```
project-root
 - userDir
 - node
    - libs
      - lib.js
    - nodes
      - node1.js
      - node1.html
    - examples
      - example.json
    - package.json
```

You can then get npm to create the symlink to the `node` directory properly from within the `userDir` directory.

Comment: This is really weird - if I call `npm install ./` from within `./mymodule` directory it does not create a symlink within `./mymodule/node_modules`. But if I call `npm install ./mymodule` from upper directory - it creates `node_modules` in upper directory (the one I am calling from) with the symlink under `node_modules/mymodule`. But in the later case it not clear from what directory I should call the `npm run debug`? (BTW in both cases the symlink was not created under userDir)

Comment: Ahh, yeah  npm always walks up the directory tree looking for a node_modules. So you can't have the userDir be inside your node directory,. It has to be one level up

Comment: When I run `npm install ./node from project-root` - everything installs properly, but If I run `npm run --prefix ./node` from `project-root`, it tries to execute "main": "index.js" from package.json and it fails..... I was unable to properly run scripts when using `--prefix` argument... Also all relative paths inside ./node directory are no longer working

Comment: Who said anything about using the --prefix option? I certainly didn't. You should be running `npm install ../node` from inside the `userDir` directory

Comment: And where should I run the `npm run command` from? And what should be the exact syntax?

Comment: The script/debug line is exactly as it was before except `--userDir ../userDir`